# How can I return a Json if it pass criteria

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Hi I have a Json api for blog, In which I want to test and return one blog that has the highest likes but I couldn't get that done for two days now and I really made research and I can't solve am using JEST to test. I'll appreciate your help. Here is the api.

```
const blogs = [ 
    { 
        _id: "5a422a851b54a676234d17f7", 
        title: "React patterns", 
        author: "Michael Chan", 
        url: "https://reactpatterns.com/", 
        likes: 7, 
        __v: 0 
    }, 
    {   _id: "5a422aa71b54a676234d17f8", 
        title: "Go To Statement Considered Harmful", 
        author: "Edsger W. Dijkstra", 
        url: "http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html", 
        likes: 5, 
        __v: 0 
    }, 
    {  
        _id: "5a422b3a1b54a676234d17f9", 
        title: "Canonical string reduction", 
        author: "Edsger W. Dijkstra", 
        url: "http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD808.html", 
        likes: 12, 
        __v: 0 
    }, 
    {   _id: "5a422b891b54a676234d17fa", 
        title: "First class tests", 
        author: "Robert C. Martin", 
        url: "http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2017/05/05/TestDefinitions.htmll", 
        likes: 10, 
        __v: 0 
    }, 
    {  _id: "5a422ba71b54a676234d17fb", 
        title: "TDD harms architecture", 
        author: "Robert C. Martin", 
        url: "http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2017/03/03/TDD-Harms-Architecture.html", 
        likes: 0, 
        __v: 0 
    }, 
    {   _id: "5a422bc61b54a676234d17fc", 
        title: "Type wars", 
        author: "Robert C. Martin", 
        url: "http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2016/05/01/TypeWars.html", 
        likes: 2, 
        __v: 0 
    }     
]
```

And this is my function.

```
const favouriteBlog = array => {
    array.map(element => {
        // return Math.max(element.likes)
        element.forEach(blog => {
            if(Math.max(blog.like)) {
                return blog
            }
        });
    });
}
```

And this is my test function here.

```
test('when blog has most likes', async () => {
    const result = listHelper.favouriteBlog(blogs)
    expect(result).toEqual(
    {
        title: 'Canonical string reduction',
        author: 'Edsger W. Dijkstra',
        likes: 12
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Math.max must take more then one parameters, and it will return the greatest, with one argument it will always return that one immediately.

You need to persist the current greatest between function calls like this

But i would not loop at all and use a one liner

```js
const blogs = [ 
    { 
        _id: "5a422a851b54a676234d17f7", 
        title: "React patterns", 
        author: "Michael Chan", 
        url: "https://reactpatterns.com/", 
        likes: 7, 
        __v: 0 
    }, 
    {   _id: "5a422aa71b54a676234d17f8", 
        title: "Go To Statement Considered Harmful", 
        author: "Edsger W. Dijkstra", 
        url: "http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html", 
        likes: 5, 
        __v: 0 
    }, 
    {  
        _id: "5a422b3a1b54a676234d17f9", 
        title: "Canonical string reduction", 
        author: "Edsger W. Dijkstra", 
        url: "http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD808.html", 
        likes: 12, 
        __v: 0 
    }, 
    {   _id: "5a422b891b54a676234d17fa", 
        title: "First class tests", 
        author: "Robert C. Martin", 
        url: "http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2017/05/05/TestDefinitions.htmll", 
        likes: 10, 
        __v: 0 
    }, 
    {  _id: "5a422ba71b54a676234d17fb", 
        title: "TDD harms architecture", 
        author: "Robert C. Martin", 
        url: "http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2017/03/03/TDD-Harms-Architecture.html", 
        likes: 0, 
        __v: 0 
    }, 
    {   _id: "5a422bc61b54a676234d17fc", 
        title: "Type wars", 
        author: "Robert C. Martin", 
        url: "http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2016/05/01/TypeWars.html", 
        likes: 2, 
        __v: 0 
    }     
]

const favouriteBlog = array => {
   var currentmax=0;
var maxblog=null
    array.forEach(element => {
            currentmax=Math.max(currentmax,element.likes)
            //console.log(currentmax)
if (currentmax==element.likes) maxblog=element
})
console.log(maxblog)
return maxblog
} 

favouriteBlog(blogs)
var array=blogs
var method2=array.find(ele=>ele.likes==Math.max.apply(null,array.map(v=>v.likes)))
console.log(method2)
```

Comment: The test still fails with both of the solutions, I console.log(maxblog) I got null